# Customise Status codes in place of 500: Internal Server Error in FastAPI using Postman

Tags: fastapi, postman-testcase

I'm very new in using FastAPI and postman. When I am sending a POST request with a body (input data), I'm getting Success code 200 and also intended Response.

Now, I want to tweak my input data to make my code fail intentionally. This is also happening. But the status code is coming to be **500** and *Internal Server Error* is being displayed in response.

I want to manually give a status code in each case of failure and also some related output in Response. How to achieve this goal?

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detailed Solution can be found out on https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/.

A quick solution is to just add following line in the function where you are returning output using try and except statements:

```
try:
    output
except Exception:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=406, detail="New Error Found")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to JSON response format, this might be helpful

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi import status

def my_function():
    return JSONResponse(
                status_code=500,
                content={
                         "code": status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                         "message": "Internal Server Error"}
            )
```

Comment: I needed to give manual status codes. Is it possible here?

Comment: Yeah, possible. Change the status code as you want.
See this list https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/status.py .
If not found any relevant, Just put manual code.

Comment: Okay.. Could you show an instance with status code 406 and detail as "Solver TimeOut"?

Comment: Just change the status code.
JSONResponse(
                status_code=406,
                content={
                         "code": 406
                         "message": "Solver TimeOut"}
            )